# Plotting multiple lines from two lists with matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, line

In the following code, a,b,c represent three expressions: 10x+7y=200, 11x-8y=63, and x+y=42. I would like to graph each of these expressions and I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is.

When I yield the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set minimum graph boundary
xMin = 0
yMin = 0

#a,b,c variables pulled from multiple expressions (ax+by=c)
a = [10,11,1]
b = [7,-8,1]
c = [200,63,42]

def init():
    #Create x,y lists // These will contain x,y plots
    x = []
    y = []

    def findxy(a,b,c):
    #Analyzes instances of (ax+by=c) and returns x,y; appends them to lists

        #Finds x,y for ax+by=c
        x.append((-b*yMin)/a + c/a)
        y.append((-a*xMin)/b + c/b)

    def printxy(x,y):
        #Prints results of findxy, followed by "z = 15x + 15y"
        if x >= xMin:
            print '(%s, %s)' % (x,yMin), 15 * x + 15 * yMin
        if y >= yMin:
            print '(%s, %s)' % (xMin,y), 15 * xMin + 15 * y

map(findxy,a,b,c)
map(printxy,x,y)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

... I get the following result:

```
>>> 
(20, 0) 300
(0, 28) 420
(5, 0) 75
(42, 0) 630
(0, 42) 630
```

... where (20,0),(0,28) represent the first expression, 10x+7y=200; (5,0) represents the second expression, omitting one ordered pair because it violates the x≥0 condition (although appending it to x,y, respectively), and (42,0),(0,42) represent the final expression.

How can I convert each of these expressions to its own line to be printed with matplotlib? I've considered creating a new list, line[], that each pass through findxy() will append x,y to line[n+1], but I'm not certain if that's a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

a = [10,11,1]
b = [7,-8,1]
c = [200,63,42]

#ax + by = c
# y = (c - ax)/b
for (ai,bi,ci) in zip(a,b,c):
    y = (1.0*ci - ai*x)/bi #multiply by 1.0 to get floats. 

    plt.plot(x,y, label="{a}x + {b}y = {c}".format(a=ai, b=bi, c=ci))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

version using subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil, sqrt

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

a = [10,11,1]
b = [7,-8,1]
c = [200,63,42]

nPlots = len(a)
gridSize = int(ceil(sqrt(nPlots)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(gridSize, gridSize)

#ax + by = c
# y = (c - ax)/b
for i, (ai,bi,ci) in enumerate(zip(a,b,c)):
    y = (1.0*ci - ai*x)/bi #multiply by 1.0 to get floats. 

    ax.flat[i].plot(x,y, label="{a}x + {b}y = {c}".format(a=ai, b=bi, c=ci))
    ax.flat[i].legend(loc=0)

#clear empty plots if not enough to fill the whole grid.
for j in ax.flat[i+1:]:
    j.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: +1. I think this answer could be improved by using `plt.subplots` to create `figure` and `axes` objects, and then plotting against the `axes` object directly.

Comment: @PaulH yeah that would be a good idea. I added a legend with the parameters for the lines. I can add a version using subplots also.

Comment: This first one worked out pretty well, but if   y = (1.0*ci - ai*x)/bi   how can I set the grid to only show me y=np.linspace(0,10,100) without altering the lines?

Comment: Unsure what you mean. do you mean plotting a y=x line? plotting a horizontal line? setting the limits of the y-axis?

Comment: @PaulH Is it also faster or just more flexible with the subplots approach?

Comment: @Lorenz mostly it's more explicit.

Comment: @PaulH and if I have lets say a 10000 curves. Is there no other way than to plot each of them per loop? This takes a lot of time. Though that is rather a new question of course.

Comment: @Lorenz you'd want to use a LineCollection for that. But that is completely orthogonal to the `pyplot` vs object-oriented interface issue, which was the basis of my comment

Comment: @PaulH Finally, I could replace the loop over the 10000 plotted lines with one single LineCollection(). This uses plt.subplots(): "In order to efficiently plot many lines in a single set of axes, Matplotlib has the ability to add the lines all at once.", see a good example at https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about matplotlib is its function integration - you can directly apply your formula to a numpy array in the plot function.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

def funcfunc(a,b,c):
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
    for pos, val in enumerate(a):
        cox, coy, coz = val, b[pos], c[pos]
        pyplot.plot(x, (coz-cox*x)/coy)
    pyplot.show()
```

This function will generate a plot, between -10 and 10 of your lines (on the x-axis).